# Thermocouple and multimeter

Tags: code-review, code-optimization, voltage, voltage-divider

I've put together this script that should allow my Arduino Mega to be show thermocouple readings on the serial monitor, whilst also showing readings of voltage and ohms across a given component. I'd be grateful for any advice on how it can be improved/streamlined:

```cpp
#include <SparkFun_MCP9600.h>
MCP9600 tempSensor;
int analogPin = 0;
int raw = 0;
int Vin = 5;
float Vout = 0;
float R1 = 220;
float R2 = 0;
float buffer = 0;
float volt = 0;
int input = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(100000);
  tempSensor.begin();

  if (tempSensor.isConnected()) {
    Serial.println("Device will acknowledge!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Device did not acknowledge! Freezing.");
    while (1); //hang forever
  }

  if (tempSensor.checkDeviceID()) {
    Serial.println("Device ID is correct!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Device ID is not correct! Freezing.");
    while (1);
  }

  pinMode(A4, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  input = analogRead(A4); //analogRead function is used to receive analog data
  volt = (input * 5.0) / 1024.0; //formula using for perform action

  if (tempSensor.available()) {
    Serial.print("Thermocouple: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getThermocoupleTemp());
    Serial.print(" °C   Ambient: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getAmbientTemp());
    Serial.print(" °C   Temperature Delta: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getTempDelta());
    Serial.print(" °C");
    Serial.println();
  }

  raw = analogRead(analogPin);
  if (raw)
  {
    buffer = raw * Vin;
    Vout = (buffer) / 1024.0;
    buffer = (Vin / Vout) - 1;
    R2 = R1 * buffer;
    Serial.print("Vout: ");
    Serial.println(Vout);
    Serial.print("R2: ");
    Serial.println(R2);
    Serial.print("voltage is:");
    Serial.println(volt);
    Serial.print("current is:");
    Serial.println(volt / R2);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: "should allow": does it, or doesn't it?

Comment: Does the code work as it is? I see you’re defining some variables  (like Vin, R1, analogPin) that are never changed and actually only used as constants. You should define them as “const” or use #define (for example for the analog port numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not very long, but I already see a few things that I would change.

```
int analogPin = 0;
[...]
pinMode(A4, INPUT);
```

These usages of pins are inconsistent. I personally prefer settings at the beginning of the file, so I'd expect

```
int analogPin = 0;
int whateverPin = A4;  // I don't have a good name yet
```

While you have

```
pinMode(A4, INPUT);
```

there's no

```
pinMode(analogPin, INPUT);
```

The main loop is doing 2 things: a) show temperature reading and b) show the component specs. This would be more obvious if written like this:

```
void loop() {
  input = analogRead(A4); //analogRead function is used to receive analog data
  volt = (input * 5.0) / 1024.0; //formula using for perform action

  showTemperatureReadings();
  showComponentReadings();    
}
```

Now, that looks a bit strange, don't you think? What about the stuff before these two big `show...()` methods? These two lines clearly belong into `showComponentReadings()`.

Now, a lot of variables are declared outside of methods. This makes them global variables. It's possible to change them from anywhere in the code. When the project grows, side effects are evil. Let's remove as many of them as possible.

You can get rid of:

```
int input = 0;
float volt = 0;
float buffer = 0;
float R2 = 0;
float Vout = 0;
int raw = 0;
```

After this change, I think the `setup()` method could be more concise. A lot of stuff just deals with the temperature sensor. I would extract a method as well.

The error messages like

> Device did not acknowledge! Freezing.

could not mean very much to the user. A message like

> Temperature sensor did not acknowledge! Check the wiring and press the reset button to retry.

could give more meaningful instructions.

The final code with these suggestions applied:

```
#include <SparkFun_MCP9600.h>
MCP9600 tempSensor;
int analogPin = 0;
int whateverPin = A4;
float R1 = 220;
int Vin = 5;

void setupTemperatureSensor() {
  tempSensor.begin();
  if (tempSensor.isConnected()) {
    Serial.println("Temperature sensor acknowledged.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Temperature sensor did not acknowledge! Check the wiring and press the reset button to retry.");
    while (1); //hang forever
  }

  if (tempSensor.checkDeviceID()) {
    Serial.println("Temperature sensor ID is correct.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("The temperature sensor ID does not have the expected value. Do you use a different sensor type? Use a SparkFun MCP9600.");
    while (1);
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(100000);

  setupTemperatureSensor();

  pinMode(whateverPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(analogPin, INPUT);
}

void showTemperatureReadings() {
    if (tempSensor.available()) {
    Serial.print("Thermocouple: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getThermocoupleTemp());
    Serial.print(" °C   Ambient: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getAmbientTemp());
    Serial.print(" °C   Temperature Delta: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getTempDelta());
    Serial.print(" °C");
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void showComponentReadings() {
  int input = analogRead(whateverPin); //analogRead function is used to receive analog data
  float volt = (input * 5.0) / 1024.0; //formula using for perform action
  int raw = analogRead(analogPin);
  if (raw)
  {
    float buffer = raw * Vin;
    float Vout = (buffer) / 1024.0;
    buffer = (Vin / Vout) - 1;    
    float R2 = R1 * buffer;
    Serial.print("Vout: ");
    Serial.println(Vout);
    Serial.print("R2: ");
    Serial.println(R2);
    Serial.print("voltage is:");
    Serial.println(volt);
    Serial.print("current is:");
    Serial.println(volt / R2);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  showTemperatureReadings();
  showComponentReadings();
}
```

With code folding active, I'd say it's now very simple to get an overview of what the code is doing and what can be configured:

[image: Code folded]

---

Edit:

After you linked to [the schematics](http://www.circuitbasics.com/arduino-ohm-meter/), I would

- rename `whateverPin` to `voltageDividerPin`.
- change the calculation `float volt = (input * 5.0) / 1024.0;` to a mapping, because it maps the 1024 input values to 5V, so `float volt = map(voltageReading, 0, 1024, 0, Vin);`
- remove `analogPin` completely, because it's not used in the original code as well.

I also hope that read the article and you understood the consequences of using a 220 Ohm resistor.

Comment: Re “_I'm not sure whether `analogRead()` works [with `0` as an argument]_”: It does. `analogRead()` treats `A0` ([defined as `54` on the Mega](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.2/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h#L51-L83)) as [equivalent to `0`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.2/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L42-L55).

Comment: The ohmmeter code came from here: http://www.circuitbasics.com/arduino-ohm-meter/ 
I'm guessing the circuit layout is still fine?

Comment: @Chris: I've updated the answer according to the schematics

Comment: It'll be 220mOhm in my case as the unknown resistance should be around there. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chris: 5V/440mOhm=11A. The Arduino can handle a maximum of 500 mA on its 5V pin. Also, you need a 28W resistor to handle the power, otherwise it'll go up in flames. It's ok, if you have considered all the electrical stuff. I just don't consider that the "normal" Arduino usage.

Comment: I'm using 1kOhm resistors to keep the overall circuit resistance down. There are three connecting the breadboard to the 5V source, GND and the analog-read pin.  But fundamentally I need the Arduino to identify the unknown resistance, which just happens to be tiny in this case.